# Show a link in jquery datagrid

Tags: jquery, mason

I have a jquery grid and I need to show a link in one of the columns. The link will have a  parameter that will be obtained from the server side. For ex:

certificateIdentifier is a server side variable. And I need to show the value of this variable in the grid. So I need to show a different value for each column. Please tell me how I can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

{
                  name: 'certificate_identifier',
                  index: 'certificate_identifier',
                  width: 300,
                  editable: false,
                  sortable: false,
                  title: false,
                  formatter:function(val) { return ''+val+'';
                      }, 
              }],